# documentation references from xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, documentation

As someone new to C and iPhone development, I'm making lots of use of the documentation.

The "doc sets" pull down has only "iPhone OS3.1" library selected.

However, sometimes when I highlight text in my source - eg "sqrt", right click, and choose "find text in documentation" I get a bunch of "Mac OSX Manual Page" hits, with pages titled "BSD Library Functions Manual".

Do I have some configuration setting wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually in the docs. Use go to **edit: declaration** to see it. Things like that (e.g. `M_PI`) are usually pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Ok - you're saying there is no iPhone documentation for eg "sqrt" and I should just use the definition. This being the case is it normal for all the Mac OS X manual pages to be presented?

Comment: There's a search function that will look through everything for the string you give it rather than look up the actually definition in the appropriate class doc. That sounds like what you got. Yeah it's standard to see it. You'll get comfy with the docs soon though, they're pretty easy to use and usually very helpful.

Comment: Also, in your code. Hold option and double click on a symbol to get a mini popup definition. You can press the book in the top right for full definition, or click show declaration if it's not in the docs.